# How to use Webstorm 8 Color Picker in all type of sourcecode files?

Tags: javascript, extjs, webstorm, color-picker

I am currently using ExtJS and we put sometimes color information into javascript files (I know, that's a big sin, but not the question).

With an effort I find a solution to activate the color picker within a javascript file:

FILE >> SETTINGS >> KEYMAP >> SHOW COLOR PICKER -> Right mouse click -> Add Keyboard Shortcut

and I've added ALT+C. So far, so good.

If I activate the color picker, I can choose a color and see the Hex-Code of it. Then I click on the choose button, nothing happens. Every time I've to select+copy+paste the color value to use it in the javascript file.

Do you know, why choose button does not apply the color value into the source code? Is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: Sublime can do that easily..

Answer (score 1):

This action only works in certain contexts (CSS, LESS, etc.). Using color picker for editing color information in javascript is not supported. Please vote for [WEB-7899](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7899) and related tickets

Comment: For those new to WebStorm: the use of the color picker is not by selecting the text, then the picker but much simpler: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/changing-color-values-in-style-sheets.html